# How to tell how many requests are waiting to be served?

Tags: node.js

At times my app does need to do some blocking operations (simple math calculations). As a result other requests will be blocked till the calculation is completed. Is there a way to count the number of requests that are waiting ?

EDIT: Adding more details - The blocking operations are very small (perhaps just simple addition of numbers, or loops of additions/ multiplication `Eg: var foo = 3 + y;`), but the point is that anything that is not IO, is probably a blocking operation. When there aren't many users accessing the site, this may not be noticeable, because the calculation is very quick. But as more users access the site, the experience gets much worse.

EDIT: If this feature isn't there, I think it would be useful. Because then we would know when to start up a new server (e.g.: an AWS server or other cloud provider). Running at full capacity is ok if we can meet all the requests, but not ok if requests start to pile up. XD

Comment: Does some simple math actually block time?

Comment: Yes. But you won't notice it because it happens so fast. A complex calculation is just a series of many simple calculations, so its easy to believe that they take time. But even small simple calculations add up, if you do many of them. For example. If you did the calculation mentioned above a million times, don't you think it would take longer, and block ?

Comment: @John, doing a couple of (thousands of) additions in a loop will pretty much go unnoticed in the grand schema of things. i.e.: handling the request/response cycle is far costlier. Having said that you could easily watch the 99 percentile latency of requests. If is starts to grow beyond a certain threshold you could add a server.

Comment: @John in that case you can force it not to block with `setTimeout(calcFn, 0)`

Comment: @Geert-Jan The above was just an example. The actual calculation is costlier and takes almost 3ms. How do you watch the latency of requests ?

Comment: @SecondRikudo The calculation always takes the same amount of time. Even if you call it as a callback, it is still going to block, since the code is synchronous! XD Or did I misunderstand you ?

Comment: @John, you monitor your app from the outside, using some app-monitoring or packet/request monitoring software. A good and free one is [PacketBeat](http://packetbeat.com/) for instance.

Comment: `setTimeout(longBlockingFunction, 0)` runs the longBlockingFunction asynchronously, so it no longer blocks.

Comment: @John, as to Second Rikudo's answer (and I'm sure he agrees), the calculation no longer blocks the response, giving time for other requests to start. That's correct. However, if you're really CPU-bound in the end it doesn't matter if you use `setTimeout` since you're just delaying your calculations not skipping them. There's no way to get past a CPU-bound process by just making part of the calculations asynchronous. After all, a node process runs on a single CPU, there's no way around that, besides running another node process on another CPU of course.

Comment: @Geert-Jan That is what I thought.

Answer (score 0):

You can not count the number of waiting requests, because they are really just queued instructions, and by time your code to "count" ran, the queue would be empty again.  JavaScript is single threaded, so unless you're running async, you'll never even get swapped-in in time.

If you want to manage this, implement your own queueing mechanism, and manage the work yourself.  The [`async`](https://github.com/caolan/async#queueworker-concurrency) package can provide this for you.